# script to pick the most recent file created in a folder in a distributed system?

Tags: windows, powershell, ant, vbscript, batch-file

script to pick the most recent file created in a folder?

The scenario is as beloow:

I have to pick the 2 files which are created recently and i have to copy it to another folder. What script can be used to perform this in a distributed system?

Comment: Are you on a platform that supports tools such as `gamin` or `inotify(7)` to be alerted when directory entries are created or unlinked?

Comment: Language and platform would help! Windows, Linux, Andoid? bash,perl, .bat?

Comment: Windows system..... Ant script, VB script or bat any of these is ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered to use powershell? It's a great tool for this kind of tasks

```
gci c:\source | ? {-not $_.psiscontainer} | 
sort-object creationtime -desc | select -first 2 | copy-item -destination c:\destination
```

This script searches only files within a specified folder, then it sorts files in reverse order by creation time, retrieves only the 2 more recents and finally copy them in you destination folder.
Very simple with a short code.
Hope that it helps.